# How to make a .env file from data in matlab?

Tags: matlab

This is a part of my code where I'm downloading MERRA data and get meteorology data out using ncread. I wonder how I can save this data as columns in a .env file? The data is represented as vectors.

```
ncdisp(file);
lon = ncread([file], 'lon')
lat = ncread([file], 'lat');
temp= ncread([file], 'T');
```

Comment: a .env file (environment variable) is pretty much like a text/csv file, you should be able to save it as a text file and add the extension yourself. ofc if we are talking about the same .env file as stated here https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/ ; you may want to add strings such as "lon =" in front of your numerical result, but in the end you are looking to output String formats to a text file in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your lon,lat and T as row vectors:

```
data = [lon' lat' T'] ;
save('env.mat','data')
```

Comment: Thank you. I have  a problem opening the env.mat file? is it possible to save it as a text file?